# Compare Packed decimal Julian date with (Packed decimal Current Julian date-7days) using JCL- SYNCSORT?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I have a requirement as below.

In my Input file, I have Packed decimal Julian date[YYYYDDD format] in 23rd position (position 23, length 4).

1. If my the input Julian date is less than (Current Julian date - 7 days) then write the records into Out File1.
2. Else Write the records into Out file2.

Can anybody let me know how to Compare Packed decimal Julian date with (Packed decimal Current Julian date-7days) using JCL- SYNCSORT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this...

```
SYSIN  DD *
SORT FIELDS=COPY,
OUTFIL FNAMES=01,
INCLUDE=(23,4,PD,EQ,DATE3P-7)
OUTFILF FNAMES=02,SAVE
```

DATE3P gives the current date in P'YYYYDDD' packed decimal format.